# Ошибка запроса по MySQL

Tags: mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в запросе.

```
material (
    id_material,
    prices 
)

nalichie (
    id_sclad,
    id_material
    kol
)

sclad (
    id_sclad
)
```

Все материалы с ценой больше 100 такие, что на каждом складе этот материал имеется в наличие в  количестве больше 2;

```
select  material.name from material where  exists (select * from sclad where id_sclad in (select id_sclad from nalichie where kol>2)) and
material.prices >100;
```

Comment: Нужно найти все материалы стоимость которых больше 100 и они присутствуют на всех складах ?

Comment: можете конкретно сказать где у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так, в 2 запроса, можно в 1, но лучше не использовать:

```
SELECT  @skladNum := count(*) from sklad;

SELECT material.*, count(*) as skladCount 
FROM nalichie
LEFT JOIN material ON nalichie.material_id=material.material_id
WHERE nalichie.kol > 2 AND material.price > 100
GROUP BY nalichie.id_sklad
HAVING skladCount = @skladNum;
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем стиле правильный запрос выглядит так:

```
select material.name from material where material.id_material in (select nalichie.id_material from nalichie where kol>2) and
material.prices >100;
```

Ваша ошибка в том, что материал, который вы выводите в верхнем запросе никак не связан с материалом, который отбираете со складов по заданному количеству во вложенном запросе. Плюс судя из структуры вложенный запрос в таблицу sklad для решения данной задачи не нужен.

**UPD**

Подправил запрос, чтоб проверял наличие на всех складах:

```
select
    m.*
    from material m
    where
        (select count(distinct n.id_sklad)
            from nalichie n
            where n.id_material = m.id_material
                and n.kol > 2
        ) = 
        (select count(s.id_sklad) from sklad s)
```

Comment: Ваш запрос не проверяет наличие товара на всех складах :)

Comment: точно, подправил, должно работать

Comment: После этого база умрет :)

Comment: да запрос совсем не оптимальный, это скорее для обучения чем для практической пользы:)

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде

```
select material.name from material left join nalichie on nalichie.id_material = material.id_material AND nalichie.kol > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Оффтоп но скажу.
Лучше в таблице sclad добавить поле отвечающее за активность в данное время склада. Ведь может быть реальная ситуация когда склад на время закрывается и товар оттуда вывозится. ТОГда запрос который дал уважаемый razielsd никогда не сработает как нужно

Comment: Если расматривать вопросы оптимизации, то там вообще надо переделывать структуру базы, иначе такую базу при таких запросах легко убить можно :)

Comment: да нет, я говорю щас скорее о проектировании

Comment: можете конкретно сказать где у меня ошибка?